# Can operator '::' be overloaded in C#?

Tags: c#

IMO, This operator cannot be overloaded but I didn't find anything on web so

I need to confirm if **operator '::' can be overloaded in C#?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

You can only overload [some of C#'s operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx). `::`, the [namespace alias qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx) is not among them.

Answer (score 2):

No, it can't be overloaded.

Take a look [`Overloadable Operators (C# Programming Guide)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The [`::` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htccxtad.aspx) in C# works on namespaces, so there is nothing to override at a class level, so it cannot be overloaded.